# Is my company EASA 147 approved? How to get an EASA licence?

Tags: career, easa

I am a bit stuck with my career and just need some advice.

I am currently a technician at [Trans Maldivian Airways](http://www.transmaldivian.com/) (Twin Otter). I would like to work in an airline in the future. Is this organization EASA 147 approved?

If so, what are the necessary steps I should take to get the license? If not what should I do? I did not do any basic training and I am completing modules conducted by SR Techniques.

Comment: If you remove the `what should I do` portion of the question, there would be no reason to close as opinion based - the rest of the questions seem rather fact-based. Not sure that _job_ advice is appropriate to SE, but opinion based wouldn't be a reason to close.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you should do, but this company is not EASA 147 certified. [Source](http://www.google.co.in/url?q=http://easa.europa.eu/system/files/dfu/Foreign_EASA_Part_147_14.pdf&sa=U&ei=JPhlVbbgGM_voAT6sYDQAg&ved=0CA0QFjAB&usg=AFQjCNETIWJpWw4v9Mu5jLAXBJ_xAqiBsw)

Comment: Without more detail this would be better as a comment.

Comment: @fooot The question was "is this company EASA 147 approved" and the answer is "No".  How does this not answer the question?

Comment: @Lnafziger I didn't say that it doesn't answer the question. I see the comment requesting the removal of the "what should I do" part, so this answer does cover it. But it does not provide much detail or explanation.